# ContextMenu (on right click) on GridView Header Line

Tags: wpf, gridview, tooltip, contextmenu

I am looking on how to add a ContextMenu on the header of my GridView.
I don't want to add it on the Column's header, but on the full "line" where are all my headers. So even if the user hides all columns, the tooltip will still be available.

Concretely, I want to be able by right-clicking in the headers line, to make appear a ToolTip, containing a list of Comboboxes, corresponding to which columns I want to see or hide.

For now I only found how to launch an event on right-click on header (`GridViewColumnHeader.MouseRightButtonDown`), but then I have no idea how to go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle` to set the `GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu` property:

```
<GridView>
  <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>    
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem>
              <MenuItem.Header>

                <ComboBox />
              </MenuItem.Header>
          </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Problem here is I need to define a ContextMenu for each header, and I want one context header for all headers (included header out of columns). I found a beginning of answer, and still working on it, will now edit my question, thanks anyway

Comment: I don't understand you. This style applies to all column headers. So each header shares the same context menu. What do you mean?

Comment: my apologies, I read too fast your post... I will try it right now thanks.

Comment: so I am trying it, but GridView has not possibility to add `ColumnHeaderStyle`

Comment: Forgot to say, I am using ListView/GridView, and not DataGrid

Comment: Ah, my bad. I updated the answer. Will work with a `GridView` now.

Comment: Declaring this `Style` (once) the `ContextMenu` will now be displayed on every column header of the `GridView`.

Comment: perfectly perfect, thanks a lot, you save my day :)